# Яке походження прізвища Дорошенко?

Tags: етимологія, власні-назви

Зрозуміло що першим кроком треба відкинути закінчення "-енко". Та саме слово "дорош" викликає питання - що це означає?

Пошук дає людей у котрих "Дорош" - прізвище. Є версія що Дорош - це спрощене ім'я Дорофій (або навіть походить від єврейського імені Дорон - "подарунок"), або що це якось пов'язане з козацтвом.

Отже питання таке - яка версія найбільш обґрунтована?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Прізвище *Дорошенко* походить від грецького імені [*Дорофій*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%96%D0%B9).

*Дорофій/Дорофей* =
δώρον `/дорон/`, *подарунок*
+
θεός `/θеос/`, *Бог*

А точніше, від зменшеної/народної/просторічної форми від цього імені — *Дорош*.

Власне кажучи, лексичне значення таке саме, як і в імені *Богдан*, а також [*Одарка/Дарина*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Comment: Іще Теодор/Феодор/Федір — те саме значення.

Comment: Зауважу, «Дорош» принаймні в радянські роки використовувався й офіційно в документах (кажу як онук Василя Дорошовича), то й не таке вже й просторічне.